# Setting custom font on all UIButtons

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uibutton

I want to apply a custom font to all buttons in my iOS app i've created in Xamarin. I've achieved the custom font on labels with the previous code:

```
//Labels
UILabel.Appearance.Font = UIFont.FromName("Lato-Light",16f);
```

...which affects some but not all buttons for some reason. Then I tried targeting the label on the button like so:

```
var buttonAppearance = UILabel.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof (UIButton));
buttonAppearance.Font = UIFont.FromName("Lato-Light", 16f);
```

...which does nothing. Should I be targeting button title instead? I know there are lots of questions on here concerning how to set this in Xcode but i'm working with C# in Xamarin.iOS. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `UIButton.Appearance` for this?

Comment: I tried `UIButton.Appearance.Font = UIFont.FromName("Lato-Light",16f);` but `UIButton.Appearance` does not accept `.Font`.

Answer (score 1):

So since there is no `UIButton.Appearance.Font`, you can use a C# workaround I normally use.

Make an extension method like this (inside a static class):

```
public static void ApplyTheme(this UIButton button)
{
    //Set the font on the button or whatever
}
```

Then call this from code on every UIButton in your app:

```
//In ViewDidLoad, AwakeFromNib, etc.
myButton.ApplyTheme();
```

This will give you styling for all buttons that you can modify as your app changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to set custom font to button text.

UIButton.TitleLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Lato-Light", 16f);

Comment: No need for the `;`